# PHP - SQL - Update Data on Button Click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

**This Question was created as my previous question contained 2 question instead of narrowing it down to 1**

**Aim**

When the user selects three variables to access a data, the user will then be able to click on a button to change one of the particulars of that data.

**SQL - Database Table (SchoolData)**

```
+-----+--------+------------+------------+----------------+-----------+
|  ID |  Class |   Teacher  |  YearMonth |   Description  |   Status  |
+-----+--------+------------+------------+----------------+-----------+
|  1  |  Alpha |    Sara    |  2017/01   |  Good & Clean  |  Pending  |
+-----+--------+------------+------------+----------------+-----------+
|  2  |  Alpha |    Sara    |  2017/01   |  Has 30 Chairs |  Pending  |
+-----+--------+------------+------------+----------------+-----------+
|  3  |  Alpha |    Sara    |  2017/01   |  Has 30 Tables |  Pending  |
+-----+--------+------------+------------+----------------+-----------+
|  4  |  Alpha |    Sara    |  2017/01   |   5 Subjects   |  Pending  |
+-----+--------+------------+------------+----------------+-----------+
|  5  |  Beta  |    John    |  2016/11   |   Big & Clean  |  Official |
+-----+--------+------------+------------+----------------+-----------+
|  6  |  Beta  |    John    |  2016/11   |   New Student  |  Official |
+-----+--------+------------+------------+----------------+-----------+
|  7  |  Beta  |    John    |  2016/11   | Injured Student|  Official |
+-----+--------+------------+------------+----------------+-----------+
|  8  |  Beta  |    John    |  2016/11   |   6 Subjects   |  Official |
+-----+--------+------------+------------+----------------+-----------+
```

---

**Webpage**

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                               |
| |>Select Class<|   |>Select Teacher<|   |>Select Year/Month<| |
|                                                               |
|                         (Search)                              |
|                                                               |
|                                                               |
|>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>INPUT<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<|
|                                                               |
|      {Class}           {Teacher}           {Description}      |
|                                                               |
|                                                               |
|                        (Update)                               |
|                                                               |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

- Legend

  *Drop down List - |><|*

  *Button         - ()*

  *Text Input     - {}*

---

**Webpage Description**

The **Update** button will change the "Status" of the selected data to "Pending". So if lets say the user searches for |  Beta  |    John    |  2016/11   | and clicks on the **Update** button, the "Status' for that Data will be changed from "Official" to "Pending"

But if the staff searches for a data which "Status' is already "Pending" for example, |  Alpha |    Sara    |  2017/01   |, the **Update** button will be disabled.

---

**HTML Table**

```
<!--Those data are setting for checking data existance in the database -->
<input type="hidden" name="class" value=" <?php echo $class;  ?>" >
<input type="hidden" name="date" value=" <?php echo  $getDate;  ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="teacher" value=" <?php echo  $teacher;  ?>" >
<input type="hidden" id="inputStatus" name="status" value="">
```

---

**Update Button (HTML)**

```
<td colspan="1" valign="bottom" align="left">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg update" id="btnUpdate" name="update"> Enable Re-Submit </button>
</td>
```

---

**Update Button Function(JavaScript)**

```
$(function (){
    $("button#btnUpdate").on('click', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#inputStatus").val("update");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'changeClassStatus.php'
        });
    }
}
```

---

**changeClassStatus.php (PHP)**

```
<?php
  $class  = trim($_POST['calss']);
  $teacher = trim($_POST['teacher']);
  $date   = $_POST['date'];
  $date   = $date."/01";
  $status = $_POST['status'];
  $empId = $_POST['empId'];

    if($status == 'update'])){
        $sqlUpdate = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE SchoolData SET Status='Pending' WHERE (Class=$class AND Teacher=$teacher AND ID='".$id[$i]."' AND YEAR(MonthYear)= YEAR('$date') AND MONTH(MonthYear)= MONTH('$date'));";
        $sqlExecute=$conn->query($sqlUpdate)or exit("Error code ({$conn->errno}): {$conn->error}");

        echo "Data Status Changed";
    }
?>
```

**Problem Description**

I have implemented the codes but they are not updating the status of the searched data. When I do click on the **Update** button, the data is not updated and nothing happens (No Changes and No Echo Message)

**Additional Notes**

This question is linked to [PHP - SQL - Disable, Hide or Enable Button based on Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47807323/php-sql-disable-hide-or-enable-button-based-on-data). If there are any lacking or inaccurate information or problems with my question, please let me know. Thank you

Comment: what is error ?

Comment: In the code provided you don't send any data to the server. Nothing to update/

Comment: Actually you need to send all data through the ajax post method so that php code will work. You are not sending any data

Comment: Please add table HTML (2-3 records html), so that we can tell you how you can grab all data and send to your PHP

Comment: `$conn->query($sqlUpdate)` will give you an error, since you already executed the query in the line before, and you are executing an update, so `mysqli_query` returns a boolean.

Comment: @manikantgautam Thank you for your reply, No Error is displayed, just that after I click on the Update Button, nothing happens. Its like the button has no function.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Thank your for your reply, but I wasn't aware of that. I thought the `  $class  = trim($_POST['calss']);
  $teacher = trim($_POST['teacher']);
  $date   = $_POST['date'];
  $date   = $date."/01";
  $status = $_POST['status'];
  $idd = $_POST['id'];` were sending the data over to the other file. I'm very new to PHP and JQuery

Comment: @MarceloOrigoni Thank your for your reply, I wasn't aware that I wasn't sending any data. I'll be editing my question shortly. What codes would you suggest me to connect the SQL query

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh Thank your for your reply, I will be editing my codes shortly. I wasn't aware that I was not sending any data forward. I'm very new to this :(

Answer (score 1):

In your If statement lets start but trying to see if all of your variables are being passed into your query correctly you can do this by writing.

```
echo $class;
echo $teacher;
etc ....
```

Inside of your if statement before your query.

I noticed `$class  = trim($_POST['calss']);` is it supposed to be 'class'? or calss?

Comment: Yeah its a typo, it was supposed to be class. I'll let you know about the echo messages. I will be editing my question shortly. Thank you =D

Comment: There are no echo messages. That would mean nothing is being sent :(

Comment: Another line of code that doesnt look right is this one: if($status == 'update']))       Make sure you fix your syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain to you with your code itself

```
$("button#btnUpdate").on('click', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#inputStatus").val("update");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'changeClassStatus.php'
        });
    }
```

In server-side, PHP expecting the below variables from the AJAX post request

```
$class  = trim($_POST['calss']);
  $teacher = trim($_POST['teacher']);
  $date   = $_POST['date'];
  $date   = $date."/01";
  $status = $_POST['status'];
  $empId = $_POST['empId'];
```

So your AJAX request should be rewrtitten in the below given syntax.

The above AJAX request does not contain any post parameters. You should add data attribute to it. See the example below

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { field1: "hello", field2 : "hello2"} ,
    contentType: 'application/json; 
    charset=utf-8'
});
```

Comment: I will be editing my question shortly. Thank you for your reply. I will try it out and get back to you =D

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery ajax call, pass the field variables to `data` property in JSON format as your php script gets the field variable values using $_POST, use `type` as post.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'changeClassStatus.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { calss: "hello", teacher : "hello2", date : "01/01/2017", status: "Active", empId : 12 },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response.status);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Here, your php script will get values if passed in `data` property in ajax call. In if condition, check for empty variables and update only if values are not empty.

```
 <?php
      $class  = trim($_POST['calss']);
      $teacher = trim($_POST['teacher']);
      $date   = $_POST['date'];
      $date   = $date."/01";
      $status = $_POST['status'];
      $empId = $_POST['empId'];

if((!empty($status) && $status == 'update') && !empty($class) && !empty($teacher) && !empty($date) && !empty($empId)){
        $sqlUpdate = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE SchoolData SET Status='Pending' WHERE (Class=$class AND Teacher=$teacher AND ID='".$id[$i]."' AND YEAR(MonthYear)= YEAR('$date') AND MONTH(MonthYear)= MONTH('$date'));";
        $sqlExecute=$conn->query($sqlUpdate)or exit("Error code ({$conn->errno}): {$conn->error}");

        echo "Data Status Changed";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out and get back to you. I will also be editing my question shortly =D